# Setup free shipping rule in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, shipping

I made some modifications on my customer group_id and I have now multi-select, so I can select more than 1 groups per customer and I setup a new customer group with the name **myshipping**. How I can apply free shipping if the customer have **myshipping** group assigned?

Thank you

I found this maybe will help someone to give me an idea:

**EDIT:**

```
class Anshu_ShippingFilter_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {

    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request) {
        if (!$this->_checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
            return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null) {
        $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
        if ($isLoggedIn) {

            $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
            if (2 == $groupId && 'freeshipping' == $carrierCode) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Shopping Cart Price Rules which is available out-of-the box in Magento.

Use the following fields to achieve this:

1. Under **Rule Information** tab => **Customer Groups** => Choose your desired group
2. Under **Actions** tab => **Set Free Shipping** to **Yes**

**Updated Answer**

Since you have modified the default one group per customer workflow, Shopping cart rules have problems in identifying the proper customer group ID. Check the code in the following file:

Class name - `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator`

Method name - `protected function _getRules()`

As you can see in that method, the customer group ID is being treated as a single value. But in your modified workflow, it will have multiple values. So, you need to modify this class (not only this particular method but the whole class) to suit your needs.

Comment: I already do this but the problem is like this: when the customer is assigned to one of my groups, it works well, but if you try to assign him to 2 groups simultaneously, it doesn't work

Comment: @Robert I have updated the answer

Comment: okay, but I don;t understand very well,  can you give me an example with working code?

Comment: @Robert It depends on your current implementation, so I cannot give you a working code for this scenario. The hint here is that this method is being used in the processFreeShipping() method of the same class. Go through the core code and modify it according to your implementation.